# gettin an error while calling function in vuejs error: internal at new HttpsErrorImpl (

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions

i am building an app and i need to get the data from contact form and send them to an email. But i am getting this weird error that i dont know what means.

[this is the error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDHsK.png)

this is my form.vue component

```
export default {
data(){
        return{
            typPozemku: "",
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            email: "",
            zprava: "",
        }
    },
methods: {
    submitForm(){
        const data = {
        typPozemku: this.typPozemku,
        firstName: this.firstName,
        lastName: this.lastName,
        email: this.email,
        zprava: this.zprava,
        timestamp: new Date().getTime()
        };

        const sendEmail = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('sendEmail');
        sendEmail(data)
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
            // this is where error is caused, via browser
          });

        const db = firebase.database().ref('contacts');
        db.push(data)
          .then(() => {
            console.log('Data added to Firebase');
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      }
    }
}
```

this is my firebase cloud function code

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});


const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: 'myemail',
    pass: 'mypassowrd'
  }
});

exports.sendEmail = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  cors(request, response, () => {
    

  const typPozemku = data.typPozemku;
  const firstName = data.firstName;
  const lastName = data.lastName;
  const email = data.email;
  const message = data.message;

  const mailOptions = {
    from: 'myemail',
    to: 'theiremail',
    subject: 'Nová zpráva!',
    text: `Jméno: ${firstName}\nPříjmení: ${lastName}\nTyp pozemku: ${typPozemku}\nEmail: ${email}\nZpráva: ${message}`
  };
  

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).send('Error sending email');
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
      res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://remax-4f73b.web.app/');
      res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
      res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
      res.status(200).send('Email sent successfully!');
    }
  });
  
  });
});
```

I tried multiple versions of firebase, cannot think of anything else, tried researching as well

Comment: You should edit the question to show the complete error message in the question itself, including the line of code that caused it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `firebase.functions().httpsCallable` to invoke a function that was defined with `onRequest`.  If you want to use a callable type function on both the frontend and backend, your backend needs to be defined as a callable as well using `onCall`.  See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) for more details and examples.

> It's important to keep in mind that HTTPS callable functions are similar but not identical to HTTP functions. To use HTTPS callable functions you must use the client SDK for your platform together with the functions.https backend API (or implement the protocol).